# What is the best way to load large number of components in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-dynamic-components

Okay so I have a **DashboardSharedModule** with 104 **Components** (widgets).

Then there is a customization page (**CustomizationModule**) where user can choose from 104 widget (components) and this is lazyloaded module.

Whenever I navigate to customization page, all 104 components load at once and it takes almost 4-5 seconds to load.

What is the best way to load all these components? Maybe using scrolling technique?

But whenever I import **DashboardSharedModule** in **CustomizationModule**module, it loads all the components.

What should be done to avoid 4-5 seconds of delay of components loading.

Comment: 4-5 sec is not that bad. Maybe just display a loading indicator.

Comment: So the user only experiences the delay when needing to customize the page and has to choose from all components? If that is it then the next question is how often does a user do this? If it's not that often I would recommend display a loading/progress indicator and leave it at that (5 seconds is not that long). If the user has to access this page (and thus wait) very frequently then you might have to do some additional investigation on how to pageinate the components.

Answer (score 1):

You can identify the subset of components needed and load the others in a lazy way when the user really needs it. If you are not navigating (not changing the route) who will need a way to load the components by code.

This library looks nice: https://github.com/wishtack/wishtack-steroids/tree/master/packages/reactive-component-loader you could take a look to figure out how much it fits your requirements.

Regards